# Is it ok to use flexbox in this way?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, css-position

I'd like to make a nav header menu using flexbox to make it responsive the would look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM6Iw.jpg).

My idea is to use a `display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-element: space-between;` on the main nav and then apply another `display: flex; flex-direction: row;` for the two menus, one using `justify-element: flex-start;` and the other one with `justify-element: flex-end;`

Would it be a correct method or do you think there are better ways to do the same thing? I also would like to have some dropdown sub-menu under some of those menu item, but for the moment I was just considering the main structure of the nav

Thank you!

Comment: it would be better if you add your code.

Comment: You know, in CSS, whatever works is the good method

Comment: Although using nested flex would work, but I think you should checkout subgrid. It might make the implementation nicer/cleaner. But I'm not sure...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Best way you can use flexbox is first create a class name Flex_Container then give it the common values like display: flex, flex-direction, etc etc now to which element you want to make flex container just add this class so that this will stop the repetition of the code and we can give specific styling to those elements instead of repeating the same.

Now come to your part: Yes it looks good you can nest the flex box elements but make sure you use the correct properties like justify-element property doesn't exist.

All the best.

Answer (score 1):

Nesting flex elements is an effective and sometimes necessary way to achieve the desired result. Go for it.

And it's `justify-content`, no such thing as `justify-element`.